# Why does R8 not rename all methods and classes?

Tags: android, android-studio, build, obfuscation, android-r8

I'm trying for my first time an Android Studio version with R8 that perform obfuscation and code optimization.

As the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code) says:

> **Obfuscate your code**
>
> The purpose of obfuscation is to reduce your app size by shortening the names of your app’s classes, methods, and
> fields.

I think that R8 will rename all method and class names, but if I analyze the APK through "Build -> Analyze APK..." I can read most of the original method and class names.

[image]
[image]

`Contenuti` is an Activity mentioned in the `manifest.xml`.

`mostraView` and `nascondiView` are methods created by me, they aren't in any library, they don't extend nothing, so I expected to see their name changed.

```
void mostraView(View v)
{
     v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
void nascondiView(View v)
{
     v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Is this R8's behavior correct?

How to set R8 to obfuscate all of them, or at least these two?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Andy mostraView and nascondiView are methods created by me, they aren't in any library.

Comment: @Andy not also that case. They don't extends nothing

Comment: maybe add the `you can add the -whyareyoukeeping option to the ProGuard configuration file` (referenced here: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/troubleshooting-proguard-issues-on-android-bce9de4f8a74 )

Comment: @Andy I read your link but it seems not to explain how to discover why the method wasn't renamed, but only why it wasn't removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This default rule may be the cause:

```
# We want to keep methods in Activity that could be used in the XML attribute onClick.
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
    public void *(android.view.View);
}
```

I obtained this from using diagnostic switches `-printseeds` and `-printconfiguration`.

A matched method would be (a) defined in a class extending Activity and (b) have a method signature matching the pattern (essentially any name and a View paramter).

However the only way I could reproduce your issue is if I modified the access modifier to include `public` as in:

```
public void mostraView(View v)
{
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Note the addition of the keyword `public`.  So assuming your posted code is verbatim then the default access modifier is package friend which would not match the pattern.

Anyways that's as far as I can take - was able to reproduce the problem with noted modification and provided a possible explanation based on default -keeps.

Note the term "keep" is overloaded in that it also applies to obfuscation.

Comment: Thanks, removing the `public` modifier from both methods they're renamed by R8