# NavController don't renamed after obfuscation

Tags: android, android-r8

Why after obfuscation in androidx.navigation NavControllerViewModel renamed, but NavController don't renamed?

Comment: It's probably used by reflection somewhere, which prevents it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does R8 not rename all methods and classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58680021/why-does-r8-not-rename-all-methods-and-classes)

Comment: @Nicolas Is there an easy way to find out where a class is being used through reflection?

Answer (score 0):

R8 can give some indication as to why a certain class and/or member is still in the program after shrinking/obfuscation by adding a `-whyareyoukeeping` into the configuration file. `-whyareyoukeeping` takes a class specification like the `-keep` rules and will report on the classes/members matched by that class specification. E.g. for the class `androidx.navigation.NavController` try adding the following to the configuration file:

```
-whyareyoukeeping class androidx.navigation.NavController
```

It might not say directly why it is not renamed, but can give a good indication as of why.

Comment: I am not interested in why a class is being keep, it should be keep, I am interested in why it is not renamed when other classes in the same package are renamed and I do not see an easy way to figure it out